# How to deploy Elm and Phoenix Elixir to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, phoenix-framework, elm

When trying to deploy a Phoenix/Elm project to Heroku I run into the following issue:

```
Running default compile
Elm compile: Main.elm, in web/elm, to ../static/vendor/main.js
/bin/sh: 1: elm: not found
17 Jul 15:58:21 - error: Compiling of web/elm/Main.elm failed. Command failed: elm make --yes --output ../static/vendor/main.js Main.elm
/bin/sh: 1: elm: not found

Check your digested files at "priv/static"
```

I'm using the buildpacks for Phoenix found in [the guides](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku) and brunch/elm-brunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is caused by the [elm](http://elm-lang.org/) binaries not being installed. One way to [install elm](http://elm-lang.org/install) is by using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elm), which is already available as the [Phoenix buildpack](https://github.com/gjaldon/heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static.git) uses it.

Solution: Add `elm` as a dependency in `package.json`. This will cause the Phoenix buildpack to install elm before executing the [brunch](http://brunch.io/) script.

Note that a local computer may have a separate installation of the elm binaries, potentially causing confusion. As long as versions match, this ought not be a problem. Note that to use the elm binaries installed by npm above, one has to include `./node_modules/.bin` in ones PATH (which the phoenix buildpack does). E.g. if one has a separate elm installation which is included in PATH since before, this will be used when running commands from the prompt.

Comment: Makes sense. What will happen to my dev environment though in case I've installed Elm using the installer and not npm?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect @stoft question about duplicate elm installations

Comment: @erikxiv this is gonna sound strange but would you happen to know why in some of my phoenix projects I don't need to include elm in my package.json but in others I do? It really bothers me that sometimes Elm seems to be already installed on Heroku for one project but not another. I think I did something weird when installing elm? Idk but I don't have Elm as a dependency in multiple projects that are live on Heroku. How can this be?

Comment: @heartmo I would guess that the devil is in the details as it often is. Create a new question with details from two separate projects working differently, focusing on buildpacks and dependencies, and you'll likely get an answer quickly.